# Having issues with Django forms

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I just started developing with Django and I'm having a bit of an issue with the use of a form I've created.

Currently I have a model named *SignUp* which allows users to "sign up" on the site by inputting their first and last names and their email address.

A feature I'm trying to implement deletes a user who is already signed up by the user submitting the email address they signed up with.

I have a form set up that's just a simple email field but I can't seem to figure out how to get my view to match up the form to the user and then successfully delete the user from the database.

Here is the code for the form:

```
class DeleteUserForm(forms.Form):
    email_address = forms.EmailField()
```

And here is the code for the view:

```
class DeleteUserView(generic.edit.FormView):
    template_name = 'signups/delete_user_form.html'
    form_class = DeleteUserForm
    success_url = '/users/delete/success/'

    def form_valid(self, form):

        for user in SignUp.objects.all():
            if user.email == form:    # The email attribute holds the user's
                user.delete()         # email address and the form should be
                                      # the address the user submitted to be
                                      # deleted?
                return redirect(self.success_url)

        return redirect('/users/delete/failure/')
```

Every time I try to submit an email address, I get no match, no user is deleted, and I just get redirected to my failure directory.

Anybody have an idea of what's going on?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Kamil's logic, I rewrote the field lookup and this code works:

```
duplicates = SignUp.objects.filter(email__iexact=form.cleaned_data['email_address'])
    if duplicates:
        duplicates.delete()
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

But does anyone know why the code I was using before didn't work?

Comment: It didn't work because you were comparing string object (email address) to django form instance. It would work if you replace user.email == form with user.email == form.cleaned_data['email'] but the solution above is much more cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

```
duplicates = SignUp.objects.filter(email=form.cleaned_data['email_address'])

if duplicates:
    duplicates.delete()

    return redirect(self.success_url)

return redirect('/users/delete/failure/')
```

Right, fixed the relation lookup.

Comment: I think you confused the field lookup parameters with something else but changing it to "duplicates =SignUp.objects.filter(email__iexact=form.cleaned_data['email_address'])" worked with your logic (I used iexact as the lookup type so the address could be case insensitive). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access field values via `form.cleaned_data` dictionary:

```
if user.email == form.cleaned_data['email_address']:
```